# Hex color is automatically converts into rgb. Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a paragraph. I want to provide the color (in hexadecimal) dynamically using js.

HTML CODE:

```
<p id="ta">this is a para</p>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', fnc);
function fnc() {
    var ta = document.querySelector('#ta');
    ta.style.color = "#100000";
}
```

It automatically converts into rgb form.

[image]

**Why it automatically converts into rgb?**

Comment: you can change that to hex code by using shift + click the color square when using inspect element. most browsers just convert to rgb code upon inspect element